# Adding fileGDB driver to gdal 1.11.1

Tags: gdal, installation, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I need to use the fileGDB driver in gdal, however I can't figure out how to install the driver.

This is the only kind of documentation I found but it doesn't make any sense to me:
[http://www.trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB)

Could somebody explain to me how to get this driver to work?
My OS is Windows 10 with the gdal core-1600 64-bit from GISInternals.

Comment: What operating system are you using, and how did you obtain your GDAL binaries?

Comment: That highly depends on the OS you are using. If you are on Windows for instance, the [OsGeo4W Installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) includes a GDAL version compiled with FileGDB support.

Comment: @EvilGenius Thanks, my OS is Windows 10, added it to my question.

Comment: @EvilGenius I got the binaries from: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

Comment: @Kersten I tried to uninstall my current gdal version and install it again using the OsGeo4W Installer but it didn't seem to support FileGDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've indicated that you are using the GISInternals build of GDAL/OGR:

You need to install the FileGDB plugin separately. This can be found on the same page as the GDAL-core installer. Just grab the filegdb installer that matches and install it afterward.

I.E. for the [MSVC 2010 version](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1.zip) you'll want:

- [GDAL Core](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1/gdal-111-1600-x64-core.msi)
- [FileGDB Plugin](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1/gdal-111-1600-x64-filegdb.msi)
- Any of the Python bindings...
- etc.

Comment: Is it right that in the list of formats this is called "OpenFileGDB" and that it is read-only?

Comment: @Mirko No, that's an alternate driver (see [FileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) and  [OpenFileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html)).

Comment: Hmm, because I downloaded and installed the fileGDB plugin from GISInternals but I still have no FileGDB driver when I execute "ogr2ogr --formats"